# fork() not running processes in order

Tags: c, process, fork

This code is meant to fork 4 times, and execute the hello() program each time a child process is created, and end the parent main() process last.

What I have here is creating all of the child processes, but hello() is out of order. The first child somehow runs hello() twice, and the 4th one doesn't at all.

#### First version

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int parent = getpid();
    printf("parent id is: %d\n", parent);

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        int cpid = fork();
        if(cpid==0){
            printf("child process is: %d\n", getpid());
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(int y=0; y<4; y++){
        hello();
        wait(NULL);
    }
    printf("loop ended, parent is: %d\n", parent);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Second version

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int parent = getpid();
    printf("parent id is: %d\n", parent);

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        fflush(stdout);
        int cpid = fork();
        if(cpid==0){
            hello();
            printf("child process is: %d\n", getpid());
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(int y=0; y<4; y++){
        wait(NULL);
    }
    printf("loop ended, parent is: %d\n", parent);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is what you're asking, but there's no defined order for the parent and child to execute.

Comment: please don't add screenshots of text.  copy / paste the text itself

Comment: Can we see what the `hello()` function does? Also, what makes you think the first child ran `hello()` twice exactly?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, none of your child processes are running `hello()` at all. Your child processes exit almost immediately and the parent runs `hello()` 4 times.

Comment: Also remember: in a child process, printing `cpid` will *not* print that child's PID.

Comment: To avoid confusion, when playing with `fork` in test programs like this, you should always (a) call `fflush(stdout)` before each call to `fork` and (b) call `fflush(stdout)` after each call to `printf` in a child.

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: It's also a good idea to end all your printf strings with newline. This will cause them to be flushed when writing to the terminal, and also make the output easier to read.

Comment: What's the point of printing `cpid`? It will always be `0` since you only do it in the child. It would be better to call `getpid()` in the child and print its own PID. `printf("child process: %d -> ", getpid());`

Comment: Rewriting the code entirely so that it invalidates the point made by the answer is not good etiquette.  Neither was posting images of the program.  It would be best to post the text of the original program and also add a new version — it would at least leave people less puzzled by an answer which doesn't match the current code.

Answer (score 2):

[*The second snippet was added to the question after this answer was posted. The first portion of this answer no longer applies, but the second and third portions below still do.*]

> *but hello() is out of order. The first child somehow runs hello() twice, and the 4th one doesn't at all.*

No. The children don't call `hello` at all. Each child prints `child process: 0 ->` then exits.

> *and the 4th one doesn't at all.*

The fourth one does exactly the same as the other three.

> *fork() not running processes in order*

Fork doesn't "run processes". It creates them. And processes run simultaneously, not in sequence. You'll have to take explicit action to cause the children to wait for other processes to take actions.

Comment: Note that this answer applies to the first version of the code — the second version is better (but still omits `#include <unistd.h>` so `fork()` is not declared and the code is not clean C99 + POSIX code.